# Why does the text on my webpage not stay in place when zoomed out?

Tags: html, css

Web dev. noob here! In Chrome when I zoom out on this [page](http://www.getbarterly.com/5), the text gets crunched up into the corner. It doesn't happen when I use Safari though. I'm assuming it's a CSS issue and/or the way I've entered it into HTML. I've put it on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sukhmen/1bLuptt3/).

```
.second {
font-family: helvetica neue, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: lighter;
line-height: 5px;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
width: 500px;
margin-left: -330px;

}

.third {
font-family: helvetica neue, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: lighter;
line-height: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 70px;
width: 500px;
margin-left: -330px;
}

.fourth {
font-family: helvetica neue, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: lighter;
line-height: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 30px;
width: 500px;
margin-left: -335px;
background-color: white;


<p class="second"><b>Barter</b> a textbook <b>you have</b></p>
<p class="second">for a textbook <b>you want</b></p>
<p class="second">with a fellow <b>Aggie</b> on campus,</p>
<p class="third"><b><i>now</i></b>.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
margin-left: -330px;
```

because you are using negative margin thats why it hide in the screen

and also your link is working fine in my chrome

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What I mean to say is that when I zoom out, the content gets bunched up into the top left corner like [this](http://i.imgur.com/7rsJ4HR.jpg).

Comment: yes this will happen because you are working in pixel not in percentage so when zoom out content shrinks. and it should not work in any browser. use percentage make them positioned

Comment: and use media query to change font size with screen